# can we get deltaLink for messages api irrespective of message folders

Tags: outlook, microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi, microsoft-graph-mail

synchronization works for messages in folder with this api

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailFolders/{id}/messages/delta
```

we can get all messages in mailbox with this api

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages/
```

Is there any way to synchronize messages in mailbox (as deltaLink in first api) irrespective of folders...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not today. Delta queries are only specific to a folder, there's no Delta query that allows you to get all changes in all folders.
You could request the feature on [uservoice](https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com)